# Where does HAML load its templates from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am dabbling in some existing code and I am able to render some HAML like this:

```
.content_container
    %strong{:class => "code", :id => "message"} Hello World!
```

But when the page loads, this HTML is rendered in an existing layout with a lot of the elements already defined.

I looked in config/settings/environment.rb which I was suggested to do by a HAML tutorial, but there was no mention of any other HAML code there.

Any idea how I can overwrite the header or find where the template is predefined?

Comment: Go look in your controller for that view to see what/if partials are being rendered.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall in the controller I only have this:   def index

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the template is being rendered with a layout.  look in `<app_root>/app/views/layouts/` for your missing HTML.

Comment: how can you tell? Is that a default? Thanks! :)

Comment: It is standard for rails apps, regardless of the templating language.

Comment: The `application` layout in that folder is the default.

Answer (score 0):

HAML likes files in the `views` directory that have a `haml` extension.

[The docs](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#plugin) say:

> ...all view files with the ".html.haml" extension will be compiled using Haml.